# Can username be omitted if profile picture is present for an "account options" button?

Tags: usability, buttons, login

I'm creating an account system for my website and the account controls will be in the top right corner, as shown in the samples below. The more stuff I add to the top bar, however, the more cluttered and clunky it feels. But, I need to include a button where the user may log out or edit their account settings. I'm worried that if I only show the profile picture that users will not know that they can interact with the button, however I couldn't find any statistics or information about this (I'm not even sure what to Google).

So the question is:

- Will users be able to easily figure out they can interact with the button?
- How are some ways I can make it more obvious without taking up much more space?

**Exhibit A**

[image: Only profile picture shown]

**Exhibit B**

[image: Profile picture with arrow]

**Exhibit C**

[image: Profile picture with name on right side]

**Exhibit D**

[image: Profile picture with name on left]

I'm gravitating towards Exhibit B, but I'm not sure if it's obvious enough.

Comment: Due to the spacing C and D look like `Name` and the picture are different elemenets/options. Also if you are using name how much space are you going to leave for people with ridiculously long names ?

Comment: @User112638726 I tried playing with the spacing and if it gets much closer it looks kind of awkward, because everything else is so spaced out. I set the width to where 9-10 characters could fit inside, and if it overflows it clips it with an ellipsis.

Comment: I find the exhibit A enough today if it's just for account mangement and log out (clearer than SE network log out IMO). Just for your information, Google uses email only with https://mail.google.com then change to avatar only with https://inbox.google.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no right or wrong way in doing this. It depends on who your users are, the overall look and spacing of your UI and the purpose of your application.

- If you look at Google support threads there are several discussions about users who are having trouble finding the "Sign Out" button after it was moved into the dropdown. I myself worked with users who were using Gmail for awhile, not knowing they can click on the user image to find Sign Out and other options.

Another concern I have for not displaying the name is,

*is there a case where users might switch between multiple accounts? If they can, how do they recognise which account they're logged in from if both accounts does not have a profile image?*

That is not very important depending on how the application is being used.

**If you don't have the space and you're only left with the option to just keep the profile image,**

- As the first time experience, make sure you inform the user that you
  have to click the user image to get to options like "Sign Out" or
  "Edit Profile"
- Use hover effects to indicate the profile image is clickable
- When clicked, show information on the popover like the person's name
  so that they know the account they're logged in from.
- Make sure you have a help or FAQ section explaining the possible
  problems users may come across with this type of UX.

Comment: Marked as answer for "it depends on who your users are..." and for the suggestions

Answer (score 2):

It might be instructive to look at how other big players are handling this. If the 'big guys' are doing it then it's a reasonable assumption that many of your users will be familiar with the approach. Here's a non-scientifically selected sample based on what I happen to have open in Chrome right now...

**Facebook**

Avatar | Name

**Twitter**

Avatar only

**Stack Exchange**

Avatar only [but with badges as part of the same link]

**Quora**

Avatar | Name

**JIRA**

Avatar | Downward arrow

**Zendesk**

Avatar | Downward arrow

**GitHub**

Avatar | Downward arrow

---

So, I'd say that **D** should be out - nobody uses that style and, as has been pointed out elsewhere, the 'Name' link sort of merges in to the menu items.

My preference would be for **B**. It's pretty widely used (though be aware that Zendesk, JIRA and GitHub will tend to attract more of the 'power user' types). I also think that an arrow offers greater affordance than the name link. If you decide to go for the avatar/name combo I'd make sure that the two are connected (i.e. if you hover over one, both items are highlighted) - check the way Facebook, Quora and Stack Exchange handle this.

In short: yes, the username can be omitted.